# Proxy configuration in OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: proxy, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I need to consume an API which is secured by OAuth2. For that I am using OAuth2RestTemplate. 
But am getting below error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

This is happening due to proxy issue. I Know how to set proxy in RestTemplate :

```
 SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new       SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new      InetSocketAddress("Proxy host", 8080));
```

clientHttpRequestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);

The same way I tried to set for **OAuth2RestTemplate** :

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate client =  new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), oauth2ClientContext);
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT));
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
    client.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    return client;
}
```

But it is not working and giving "Connection timed out" exception. This is happening because of this first line `OAuth2RestTemplate client =  new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), oauth2ClientContext);` which tries to get Access token that  means there also it needs proxy setting. if I add below lines then it works:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "urproxy.com");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
```

But I can not use System.setProperties("","") option as we do not have permission to set on tomcat server.

I researched but could not find any way to set proxy in OAuth2RestTemplate while creating this object.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if question is not clear. Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 14):

`OAuth2RestTemplate` just creates a set of `AccessTokenProvider` to retrieve the token from authorization server according to different kinds of grant types. For example `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider` is used to retrieve access token with grant type authorization_code. The token providers themselves initiate some `RestTemplate` to send the request but do not use `OAuth2RestTemplate` just created. One way might resolve the issue. That is to create you own `AccessTokenProvider` and set the request factory.

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
Proxy proxy= new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT));
requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);      

AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

ImplicitAccessTokenProvider implicitAccessTokenProvider = new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider();
implicitAccessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(
Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider> asList(authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider, implicitAccessTokenProvider));

OAuth2RestTemplate client = new OAuth2RestTemplate(github(), oauth2ClientContext);
client.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);
```

You could also add ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider and ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider to the OAuth2RestTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

This RestTemplate provides a workaround:

```
/**
 * An OAuth2RestTemplate with proxy support.
 * 
 * @author E.K. de Lang
 */
public class ProxySupportingOAuth2RestTemplate
    extends OAuth2RestTemplate
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LogFactory.getLogger(ProxySupportingOAuth2RestTemplate.class);

    private final SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory;

    public ProxySupportingOAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, OAuth2ClientContext context,
            AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider)
    {
        super(resource, context);
        factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        super.setRequestFactory(factory);
        super.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);

        // To fix issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/459 also set the factory of the token-provider.
        if (accessTokenProvider instanceof OAuth2AccessTokenSupport) {
            ((OAuth2AccessTokenSupport) accessTokenProvider).setRequestFactory(factory);
        }
        else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("accessTokenProvider must extend OAuth2AccessTokenSupport");
        }
    }

    public void setProxy(Proxy proxy)
    {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("setProxy:" + proxy);
        }
        if (super.getRequestFactory() == factory) {
            factory.setProxy(proxy);
        }
        else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("RequestFactory has changed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling setProxy?